# How does one configure Guard to run Rails 5 system tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

By default `rails test` does not run system tests, and one must invoke `rails test:system` in order to run the system tests. Given that one is using *Guard*, what is the proper addition to the *Guardfile* such that *guard* will:

1. Run all the tests, including the system tests.
2. Run the appropriate system test when it changes.

I have tried something like:

```
guard :minitest, spring: true do
  # ...
  watch(%r{^test/system\/?(.*)_test\.rb$})  { 'test' }
  # ...
end
```

But it seems I am not educated in configuring Guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails specifically excluded system tests from being run with `rails test` because they're much slower. The recommended workflow is to run your fast unit tests while you're working (i.e. with guard) and run system tests once you're ready to commit to confirm functionality.

If you wanted to do this anyways, you would need to either add a new Guard plugin (`guard :yourthing { ... }`), or you can simply configure your `rails test` command to also include `rails test:system` using Rake:

```
# Rakefile
Rake::Task["test"].enhance ["test:system"]
```

This will make `rake`, `rake test`, and `rake test:run` all run your system tests as well, including when they're run from Guard.

Comment: Thank you, @coreyward. I'm using Rails 5.1.4 and the addition to the Rakefile does not affect `rake`, `rake test`, or `rails test`. I'll edit the answer for accuracy.